# pptp gateway with ssh access

Tags: iptables, routing, gateway, pptp

I am desperately trying to setup a gateway-server that forwards all local traffic to a ppp0 connection but is still reachable via ssh on the local network.

The point-to-point connection establishes fine, IP-forwarding is enabled and with

```
route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 ppp0
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I almost achieve what I want. But once "route" is set, the gateway-server can no longer be reached via ssh.

I am pretty new to "route" and "iptables" and do not fully understand how they work yet but there has to be a super simple solution for my problem.

Please help!

A very similar question without proper solution: [How can I route outgoing traffic through a PPTP VPN connection on a VPS without losing SSH access?](https://serverfault.com/questions/422667/how-can-i-route-outgoing-traffic-through-a-pptp-vpn-connection-on-a-vps-without)

**EDIT:** A more detailed example below

*LOCALHOST* (192.168.0.1) --> *GATEWAY* (192.168.0.2) --> *VPN* (93.184.216.34)

GATEWAY shall be a local gateway to the internet via VPN. This is quite an easy setup as described above: Enable IP-forward, establish a PPTP connection between GATEWAY<>VPN and set a default route through ppp0 afterwards.

LOCALHOST can now use GATEWAY for internet access with VPN's IP-address **but** access to GATEWAY within the local network (192.168.0.X) via SSH does not work anymore once the PPTP connection is established.

**EDIT2:** ifconfig and route output (192.168.0.10 is the 'regular' local gateway)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 12:34:56:78:90:ab  
          inet Adresse:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maske:255.255.255.0

ppp0      Link encap:Punkt-zu-Punkt-Verbindung  
          inet Adresse:10.10.1.1  P-z-P:93.184.216.34  Maske:255.255.255.255
```

-

```
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
default         192.168.0.10    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
93.184.216.34   192.168.0.10    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
93.184.216.34   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
localnet        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Please post details about networks: ip of local host running ssh client; ip of gateway server, on the lan-side; ip of default gateway used on the lan. These are needed to define  the "route add" command that you need to substitute to the one you posted to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you show the output of `ifconfig` and `route` once everything is up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/ppp/peers/CONFIG:

```
...
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute
```

/etc/ppp/ip-up.d/CONFIG:

```
#!/bin/bash
route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.0.10 dev eth0
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
```